# Duplicate values get inserted instead composite key in xampp server phpadmin database

Tags: sql, xampp, mariasql

I had 1st created the table with only one primary key then converted 1 more column to primary key using:

```
ALTER TABLE students DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(student_id, email);
```

The composite key created successfully but composite key isn't working the way it should work.

On inserting the same values of email but with different id database inserts the value successfully isn't giving me `catch` statements

## I have tried this code:

```
 try{
        $dbhandler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project_db','root','');

        $dbhandler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql="insert into students (student_id,faculty,password,cpi,first_name,last_name,birthdate,email,contact_no,participate,leader,allocated) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,0,0)";    //   leader is 0 means not decided
        $query=$dbhandler->prepare($sql);
        $p=0;
        if(isset($_POST['s_participate']))
        {
            $p=1;
        }
        $r=$query->execute(array($_POST['s_id'],$_SESSION['faculty'],$_POST['s_id'],$_POST['s_cpi'],$_POST['s_f_name'],$_POST['s_l_name'],$_POST['s_birthday'],$_POST['s_email'],$_POST['s_contact'],$p));
}
catch(PDOException $e){
            $msg='student with this id is already exist';
            $temp=1;
            header("location:./insert_student.php?msg=".$msg);
    }
if($r){
        header("location:./insert_student.php?msg=Student ".$_POST['s_f_name']." with id ".$_POST['s_id']." is successfully added");
    }
```

Comment: A Primary Key is unique over the column *combination*, of course you can have the same `student_id` with multiple `email` or vice versa. If you want a single row per student do a PK on student_id, if you want do allow only unique emails add another UNIQUE constraint on it.

Comment: okk i got it that i just need to change the email to unique key instead of primary key